# Problem with installing pytorch in python - ctypes.CDLL(dll) - OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to run the run_placesCNN_basic.py code from https://github.com/CSAILVision/places365.
I'm running Windows 10 and Python 3.7.9.

I open the command prompt and try to install pytorch:

```
py -m pip install torch==1.6.0+cpu torchvision==0.7.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

And i get the following process:

```
C:\Users\..\Downloads\places365-master>py -m pip install torch==1.6.0+cpu torchvision==0.7.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Collecting torch==1.6.0+cpu
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.6.0%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (167.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 167.7 MB 1.8 kB/s
Collecting torchvision==0.7.0+cpu
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torchvision-0.7.0%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (362 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 362 kB 345 kB/s
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.19.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (12.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 12.9 MB 63 kB/s
Collecting future
  Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 829 kB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting pillow>=4.1.1
  Downloading Pillow-7.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 42 kB/s
Using legacy setup.py install for future, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: numpy, future, torch, pillow, torchvision
  WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
    Running setup.py install for future ... done
  WARNING: The scripts convert-caffe2-to-onnx.exe and convert-onnx-to-caffe2.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed future-0.18.2 numpy-1.19.1 pillow-7.2.0 torch-1.6.0+cpu torchvision-0.7.0+cpu
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

And finally, Im trying to run the .py file:

```
C:\Users\..\Downloads\places365-master>py run_placesCNN_basic.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_placesCNN_basic.py", line 6, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Does anyone knows why I can't run the pytorch module even if had already installed it?